# Как сделать вывод постов с разными размерами превью в wp?

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress, css3

Добрый день, подскажите как реализавать вот такой вывод постов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Непонимаю как выводить изображения разных размеров, вывод изображений собирался делать через post thumbnail, те через миниатюру, не понимаю как это должно происходить, я должен загружать миниатюры разного размера в поле задать миниатюру?, либо миниатюры должны быть все одинаковые а в цикле php как-то они должны обрезаться, миниатюры 2ух видов, горизонатльная (например 100x300) и вертикальная (300x700) в обещм я не понимаю помогите разобраться с функцией вывода постов или с реализацией в целом.

Comment: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/add-masonry-grid-layouts-to-your-wordpress-site-with-just-css/  Или плагины, например https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-masonry-layout/ Если делать самому, я советую для начала сделать рабочую версию без Вордпресса, HTML+CSS+(если нужно JS), а потом уже станет понятно, как это перенести в Вордпресс, тут ничего сложного нет.

Comment: @labris Рабочую версию я уже сделал, можно по ссылке посмотреть http://new-level.by/test/projects.html

Comment: @labris , решил разделить на две колонки module__grid__column и в каждую выводить посты, в левую и в правую. Обчыно вывожу через qyrey post, но как выводить превью разного размера не понятно, либо их загружать разных размеров, те подгонять специаьно либо как-то иначе.

Comment: Посмотрите пример тут - http://w3bits.com/labs/css-masonry/3/

Comment: Возможно, в Вордпрессе надо будет добавить новые размеры миниатюр с сохранением пропорций (add_image_size c параметром false).

Comment: Ничего не надо резать, ставить размеры и проч. Есть нормальные плагины. Все решается версткой.

Comment: @KAGGDesign   С плагинами каждый может :) См. мой первый комментарий

Comment: @KAGGDesign Насчет "ничего не надо резать" - может быть, придется все-таки подгонять размеры миниатюр под конкретный сайт. В FAQ к jQuery Masonry Image Gallery написано: All my thumbnails are the same size so they don’t stack. Can I fix this? -  Go to the Dashboard -> Settings -> Media. Make sure «Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions (normally thumbnails are proportional)» is unchecked. You can also change the size of thumbnails as well.  Then install the Regenerate Images plugin and run it. - То есть тут уже два плагина надо ставить.

Comment: @labris я делал masonry галереи, просто задавая одинаковый размер фоткам. Я о том здесь, что не надо каждую конкретную подрезать под размеры (что особенно весело звучит, когда начинаем задумываться об адаптивности) - masonry сама все делает. И адаптивность, и смену числа колонок при ресайзе окна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ищите плагины WordPress, построенные на основе jQuery-плагинов masonry или isotope.

Например:

[jQuery Masonry Image Gallery](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-masonry-image-gallery/)

[Wanna Isotope](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wanna-isotope/)

Comment: jQuery Masonry Image Gallery - только для галерей, не для постов.

Comment: А где в вопросе сказано, что он посты хочет выводить? Кроме того, тот же поиск среди плагинов выводит и те, что для постов. Все на поверхности лежит.

Comment: Вопрос так и называется: "Как сделать вывод постов с разными размерами превью в wp?" :) Про поверхность не спорю, но интереснее сделать без плагинов.

Comment: @labris Я это понял как кастомные посты, входящие в галерею, но не суть. Можно и без плагинов, надо владеть jQuery, установить masonry.js - и вперед.

Comment: @KAGGDesign простите, так что делать непонятно?, у меня всего два вида изображений один квардратный а второй прямоугольный и они всегда будут одинакого размера, мэзонри группирует их что бы они были ровно, хотя ладно мэзонри удобный вариант для компоновки елементов, но что делать с выводом самих превью, что с ними делать заливать прямоугольные и квадратные одно размера? те при загрузке изображений тупо их подгонять? Или как-то на стороне php их кропать?

Comment: Нет общего ответа. Зависит от того, сколько колонок, как компонуете. Смотрите на большом экране и ставьте загружаемый  размер под это. Ну то есть если у вас masonry при 1920 ширины выводит картинки 500×500, то так и сохраняйте